# ClosedXML OutofMemoryException on more records

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I use ClosedXML for exporting data into excel. The code is below

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
var ws = workbook.Worksheets.Add(table, tabName);
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                workBook.SaveAs(memoryStream);
                memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                memoryStream.Close();
            }
```

If I am exporting 22000+ records, I got
OutofMemoryException at this line `workBook.SaveAs(memoryStream);`

Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OutOfMemory errors using large datatables with ClosedXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43458813/outofmemory-errors-using-large-datatables-with-closedxml)

Answer (score 0):

ClosedXML cannot export a big quantities of row and data and this is disadvantage of this library.

I recommend you to use OpenXML. It is another library able to export a large quantities of data.