# OutOfMemory errors using large datatables with ClosedXML

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, streamreader, closedxml

I have an issue creating worksheets when adding large DataTables. I am getting out of memory errors. I turned off the event tracking as suggested to improve performance and memory consumption but I am still experiencing these errors.

Here is some sample code:

```
public void SaveWorkBook(string xlFileName, DataSet dataSet)
{
    using (var xlWorkBook = new XLWorkbook(XLEventTracking.Disabled))
    {
        xlWorkBook.AddWorksheet(dataSet);
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(xlFileName);
    }
}

public void SaveWorkBook(string xlFileName, params DataTable[] dataTables)
{           
    using (var xlWorkBook = new XLWorkbook(XLEventTracking.Disabled))
    {
        foreach (var dataTable in dataTables) xlWorkBook.AddWorksheet(dataTable);
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(xlFileName);
    }
}
```

The issue of course is when the DataTables are huge. Like thousands of records or more. I tried using an alternative method to large data tables like using a temporary one with smaller records counts, then flushing them to the Worksheet, clearing the data table then refilling it with new data. Fill, flush, clear, repeat. That or the `InsertData` method()

The issue is that every time I try to write the data table using the options available, only the first column is getting written. Then lower down the file I am seeing the other columns of data, but in the first cell of the worksheet instead of spanning the columns in a single row as they are suppose to. And only for 1 row. Probably for the last record that was written.

Can someone help me understand how this works?

Here is a code snippet using the `InsertData` method. I create the worksheet using a dataTable as a template since it has all the columns defined. Then I get that worksheet and try to add to it.

```
public void SaveWorkBook(string xlFileName, DataTable dataTable, string dataFileName, char delimitor)
{
    using (var xlWorkBook = new XLWorkbook(XLEventTracking.Disabled))
    {
        xlWorkBook.AddWorksheet(dataTable);

        var workSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets.First(ws => ws.Name == dataTable.TableName);                    

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(dataFileName))
        {
            var rowIndex = 1;

            sr.ReadLine();

            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = sr.ReadLine() + string.Empty;
                workSheet.Cell(++rowIndex, 1).InsertData(line.Split(delimitor));
            }
        }

        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(xlFileName);
    }
}
```

As you can see I am using a `StreamReader` to read 1 line at a time of the CSV file I created earlier. Loading the entire file into the datable causes out of memory errors. So I read the file 1 line at a time and try to add it after creating the worksheet.

Can anyone share some insight into this?

Thanks

Comment: Side note, do you care about styles (fonts, colour, etc) at all in your workbook? It's the styles that cause the excessive memory usage.

Comment: No, I don't care about styles. I care about the column widths when opening the excel file after its been written but that's about it.

Comment: For the column widths the styles are needed. The font size will affect the width of the columns. So then I don't have a workaround for you yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in ClosedXML. There is currently no solution. See the issue at https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/264